# Alternate column (<td>) classes and maybe even column content in rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cycle, html-table

In rails I know you can do

```
<tr class="<%= cycle("even", "odd") %>">
```

to cycle the class for a given row.

But in cases like this

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
<tr class="headers">
    <td><%= p.name %></td>
    <td><%= p.idnum %></td>
    ...
</tr>
<% end %>
```

how might I automatically alternate the column class?

Is there some way I could something like this? (inventing some fanciful method names ('.column_names') for sake of illustration)

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
    <tr class="headers">
        <% products.column_names.each do |c| %>
            <td class="<%= cycle("even", "odd") %>"><%= c %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: (case in point)

```
<table>
  <tr class="headers">
    <td class="even">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="odd">Name</td>
    <td class="even">Followers</td>
    <td class="odd">Date Joined</td>
    <td class="even">Slogan</td>
    <td class="odd">Location(s)</td>
    <td class="even">Segments(s)</td>
    <td class="odd">Website</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="body">
    <td class="even"><img src="<%= company.thumbnail_logo %>"></td>
    <td class="odd"><%= company.company_name %></td>
    <td class="even"><%= company.followers %></td>
    <td class="odd">...</td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I'm in the middle of writing currently, and as you can see it's fairly verbose. I'm looking to cut down on that.

Comment: If this isn't possible maybe I (or better, one of you) should try to push some changes to rails!!

Comment: Even, odd for layout can better and more easily be achieved with css. Like :nth-child(even)

Comment: could you elaborate on that in an answer please sir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this just for styling purposes?
You can use CSS3 to do this without having to assign classes.

```
tr:nth-of-type(even){ your_css_here }
```

or

```
td:nth-of-type(even){ your_css_here }
```

Replace `even` with `odd` if that's what you want

Also, wouldn't you use `<th>` for headers?

Comment: And yes, that's a good way to cut down on the verbosity, using <th>. I'll do that from now on thanks

Comment: How would I get even and odd to cycle??? I'm not sure if you've answered that. Have you answered that?

Comment: CSS cycles it, you don't have to.
You put that in your CSS:
`tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #myhexcolor; }`
And it will put that hex background color on each even row... same for columns... and of course you can apply whatever styles you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple named cycles within the same loop to achieve this effect. Here's an example using a model called `Example` and printing each of the attributes in its own `<td>` with a class corresponding to the attribute name:

```
<% @examples.each do |example| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even', :name => 'row-cycle') %>">
    <% example.attributes.each_pair do |attribute, value| %>
      <td class="<%= cycle(*example.attribute_names, :name => 'column-cycle') %>"><%= value %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

And some sample output from this code:

```html
<tr class="odd">
  <td class="id">1</td>
  <td class="name">Brandan</td>
  <td class="location">Raleigh</td>
  <td class="created_at">2012-07-21 21:14:45 UTC</td>
  <td class="updated_at">2012-07-21 21:14:45 UTC</td>
</tr>
```

You can adjust this to meet your needs if you don't want to print all of the attributes on every record.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a *cycle* helper in Rails:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle

Comment: Yes but how might I automate it for columns? All I see on the internet is how to cycle your row (<tr>) classes, not your (<td>) columns or column contents.

Comment: As you can see I've included 'cycle' in my tags